# OS X Server Lion

Tags: osx-lion, osx-server

I have a MacBook Pro and an Intel based iMac... Heard a fellow co-worker tell me that he installed OS X Lion Server on his machine just so he can install Oracle 11g and Oracle Application Server.

Been considering installing OS X Lion Server on both of my machines with the intention of having my iMac as a dedicated server.

My question is that I use both computers for general purpose computing (word processing, mail, ical, keynote, etc) but also develop software (Java, Eclipse, etc).

Would installing OS X Server Lion be an overkill (meaning is it just server software but people can't use it for other purposes such as iTunes and playing video games)?

If I did a Time Machine backup and reformatted both computers to be using OS X Server Lion would the previous Time Machine back up from just OS X Lion and OS X Snow Leopard restore everything for me?

Also, is OS X Server just OS X with some cool server applications running on it (along with UI for these server apps) or is it a completely different beast (incompatible with lots of apps)?

Would appreciate some thoughts and feedback.

Comment: Oracle 11g isn't available on Mac OS X. Oracle 10g R2 is. And I assume you're factoring the cost of Lion Server licenses in to this decision..

Comment: I highly doubt you actually need OSX Server to install Oracle, especially with Lion the "server" part is just an add-on.

Comment: @Steve-o There is no Oracle 11g for Mac - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: @todda.speot.is so doubly pointless, VirtualBox and Linux would be more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lion Server is not actually a separate version of the operating system, it's just an additional application bundle you can [download](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-lion-server/id444376097?mt=12&ls=1). So you'll still be able to use everything as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, gentlemen!